# SqlExcepction 0x80131904 in ASP.net. Website can't connect to SQL Server, error 40

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, network-programming, dotnetnuke

So I'm getting an error with my company's ASP.net website (built on an old DotNetNuke framework) today that says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

And this lists this stack:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +428
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.DiscoverSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter, Object[] parameterValues) +233
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSetInternal(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter) +343
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(String connectionString, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter) +175
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(String connectionString, String spName) +45
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, String spName, Object[] parameterValues) +207
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider.Data.SqlDataProvider.GetLogTypeConfigInfo() +71
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider.DBLoggingProvider.GetLogTypeConfigInfo() +101
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider.DBLoggingProvider.GetLogTypeConfigInfoByKey(String LogTypeKey, String LogTypePortalID) +65
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider.DBLoggingProvider.AddLog(LogInfo objLogInfo) +75
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.LogController.AddLog(LogInfo objLogInfo) +175
```

I had to take the site down recently, which I did my simply moving the files to another section of the hard drive. When I moved them back, I got this. It's connecting back to a separate server we have, but there's a block somewhere in the connection. Both machines are able to ping each other, so I'm guessing it's something on the server level? The stack is very vague to me, so I don't have the first clue of where to look for my error. Thoughts?

Comment: 1. Are you able to connect to the database using sql server management studio or using odbcad32.exe from the application server? 2. Make sure that on the machine having sql server - the sql server agent service is running

Comment: try to sql server configuration services stop to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by doing the following.

Go to http://ServerName/install/install.aspx

See if DNN gives you any additional details on the connection error.

Check the web.config connection strings. Did you setup IIS to use a dynamic account as the owner of the application pool? Does the login information in the web.config connection strings still work?